# fetch more than 20 rows and display full value of column in spark-shell

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using `CassandraSQLContext` from spark-shell to query data from Cassandra. So, I want to know two things one how to fetch more than 20 rows using `CassandraSQLContext` and second how do Id display the full value of column. As you can see below by default it append dots in the string values.

Code :

```
val csc = new CassandraSQLContext(sc)
csc.setKeyspace("KeySpace")
val maxDF = csc.sql("SQL_QUERY" )
maxDF.show
```

Output:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------+--------------------+
|                  id|               Col2|              Col3|                Col4| 
+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------+--------------------+
|8wzloRMrGpf8Q3bbk...|             Value1|                 X|                  K1|
|AxRfoHDjV1Fk18OqS...|             Value2|                 Y|                  K2|
|FpMVRlaHsEOcHyDgy...|             Value3|                 Z|                  K3|
|HERt8eFLRtKkiZndy...|             Value4|                 U|                  K4|
|nWOcbbbm8ZOjUSNfY...|             Value5|                 V|                  K5|
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

If you want to print the whole value of a column, in **scala**, you just need to set the argument truncate from the `show` method to `false` :

```
maxDf.show(false)
```

and if you wish to show more than 20 rows :

```
// example showing 30 columns of 
// maxDf untruncated
maxDf.show(30, false)
```

For **pyspark**, you'll need to specify the argument name :

```
maxDF.show(truncate = False)
```

Comment: For pyspark users who make it here, just be sure to specify the `truncate` argument name and capitalize your `False`: `maxDF.show(truncate = False)`

Answer (score 6):

You won't get in nice tabular form instead it will be converted to scala object.

```
maxDF.take(50)
```

Answer (score 1):

To show all rows of a dataframe, following can help :

```py
df.show(n=df.count(), truncate=False)
```

Please be careful not to use this on a big dataFrame.

Quick reference on the parameters to show method (pyspark version):

```
Parameters
----------
n : int, optional
    Number of rows to show.
truncate : bool or int, optional
    If set to ``True``, truncate strings longer than 20 chars by default.
    If set to a number greater than one, truncates long strings to length ``truncate``
    and align cells right.
```